# Auto desk - Forge Viewer - Markup - am not able to get markups array in markup extension while loading markups

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

While loading markups, I am not able to get markups array from markup extension as referneced in below code, actually I need client position  coordinates of the loaded markup. In below code am getting markups array empty. But while drawing a new markup, we always have markup array filled.
Please advise

```
        markup.viewer.restoreState(viewState);
        markup.loadMarkups(svgTxt, "layerName") 

        var pos = markup.markups[0].getClientPosition()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not editing the layer you specified, the `markupExt.markups` will not contain anything. Please use this instead:

```
const activeLayerMarkup = markupExt.svgLayersMap[markupExt.activeLayer]
activeLayerMarkup.markups[0].getClientPosition()
```

Or try to edit the layer

```
markupExt.loadMarkups(svgTxt, 'layerName')
markupExt.enterEditMode('layerName')
markup.markups[0].getClientPosition()
```